# How to set an email to 'Seen' in Outlook with WIN32 python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook, pywin32, office-automation

I have a code, which sends a new email to the chosen recipients. The email is created based on a received email, which is in the inbox.

For the email sending I use the Win32 python library.

However, since a brand new email is being created, the email from which the new email is created left 'unseen' in the inbox.

How can I set the original email to 'seen' with code?

The code is something like this:

```
if inbox.Items[i].UnRead == True:
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = mail_list
    mail.Subject = sub
    mail.HTMLbody = new_body
    mail.Send()
    print('The email was sent successfully!')
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> the email from which the new email is created left 'unseen' in the inbox.

You just need to set the [MailItem.UnRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.unread) property to false on that item. The property returns or sets a boolean value that is true if the Outlook item has not been opened (read).

Answer (score 0):

Try `inbox.Items[i].UnRead = False` after `mail.Send()`

Example

```
import win32com.client


def send_new_email(inbox):
    for item in inbox.items:
        if item.UnRead:
            print(item.Subject)
            new_email = outlook.CreateItem(0)
            new_email.Display()
            item.UnRead = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("outlook.Application")
    olNs = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    send_new_email(inbox)
```